# How do I make a batch filtered script executable?

Tags: shell, find, chmod

I just search (recursively) for all shell scripts within a folder:

```
$ find * | ag "\.sh\b"
```

Now how do I make them executable, like

```
$ (lambda file_list: chmod +x file_list) (find * | ag "\.sh\b")
```

Sorry for this weird Python/Shell pseudo-code, I don't know another way to convey it concisely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [Command Substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html).

Embed a command within backquotes to make it an argument for another command:

```
$ chmod +x `find * | ag "\.sh\b"`
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `find`'s `-exec` option:

```
find -type f -name '*.sh' -exec chmod +x {} +
```

The `chmod` command is built by appending each selected file name at the end: `chmod +x f1.sh f2.sh ...`. The `{}` is replaced with the current file name being processed. See `man find`.

**Concerning your current command**

Your current command is incorrect mainly because you are implicitly passing *all* nodes in the current directory to `find` due to the fact that the asterisk (`*`) is expanded to *all files in the current directory*: `find file1 file2 dir1 dir2 ...`. Obviously, not very efficient way to find all files with `.sh` extension.

The second issue is the use of `ag` tool, since `find` is very capable of searching for file names by patterns. Read about `-name`, `-path`, and `-regex` options, for instance. In order to find all files with `.sh` extension simply pass `'*.sh'` pattern to the `-name` option ("test", in terms of `find`). Note, the pattern should be escaped to prevent interpretation in the shell context.